# Step size updating scheme adaptive embedded RK methods

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

If I have a RK method $y$ of order $p$ and a RK method $z$ of order $p-1$ I have read I can estimate the local error as $r_{n+1} = y_{n+1} - z_{n+1}$. First of all I don't see how this estimates the local error defined as the error we make in a single step using correct previous values. What does a lower order method have anything to do with previous correct values? I can accept that this is the error we make using a lower order method instead of a higher order method, but what is the relevance of this?

Further, I read that the step size should be updated like 
$$h_{n+1} = \left( \frac{TOL}{r_{n+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}h_n.$$
But I don't understand why this would work since we update our step size so that $r_{n+1} = TOL$, this would just result in $h_{n+1} = h_n$ after a while. **What am I missing?**

Comment: My understanding is that you usually compare to the result that a *higher* order RK method would give (after one step from the current start point), and use that as an estimate for the error of the *lower* order method. The idea of this is more or less the same as the idea of Richardson extrapolation.

Comment: @Ian If we have already calculated the higher order method, why would we need to use the lower order method or know the error of the lower order method?

Comment: You don't: you're using the lower order method as your "main approximation" and just using the higher order method to approximate the error you make along the way with the lower order method.

Comment: @Ian But to estimate the error we need to calculate the higher order method in the new point, so why not just use it instead of the lower order method, since the higher order method is better?

Comment: In fixed step size, you'd be right. In dynamic step size, you need something "better" to use as an error estimate so you know when to make the step size bigger or smaller. (Also, it's possible that the higher order method is more locally accurate but less stable, in which case you don't want to use it over and over.)

Comment: @Ian okay that seems very counter-intuitive to me but I guess I can accept it. But is the $p$ in the formula the order of consistency for the higher order method or lower order method?

Comment: I think it'll have to be the lower order method, so that $h_{n+1}^p$ is proportional to TOL. But check your reference of course.